# Grouped Bar Chart in D3.js

Tags: ajax, d3.js

Grouped Bar chart with json data

```
data={"data":"
[
{\"indzone\":\"DO3Zone\",\"totalplot\":1506,\"allotted\":604,\"vacant\":625,\"amenities\":27
}
,
{\"indzone\":\"MysuruZone\",\"totalplot\":1382,\"allotted\":752,\"vacant\":325,\"amenities\":27},

{\"indzone\":\"BallariZone\",\"totalplot\":920,\"allotted\":701,\"vacant\":65,\"amenities\":34},
{\"indzone\":\"BelagaviZone\",\"totalplot\":2650,\"allotted\":2188,\"vacant\":262,\"amenities\":45},   

]"}
```

I want to group for each zone allotted and vacant and amenities.How to achieve this with d3.js

Comment: May i know grouping means? Are u looking for a grouped/stacked bar chart. please provide the details

Comment: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051

Comment: Ya Grouped bar chart only.I saw that example already but i am not able to group the fields like allotted,vacant,amenities..can u please help me how to group for my json data.

Comment: which version of d3 are you using is it d3.v3 or d3.v4

Comment: Yes it is working correctly.Thank you so much

Comment: how to refresh the data

Comment: make it as a function and feed the data everytime https://bl.ocks.org/caravinden

Comment: @AravindCheekkallur i am trying to update the bar chart on dropdown change of indzone.i am not able to refresh the chart.it is adding one more chart.i am using sel.exit().remove();
sel.enter().append("rect")

Comment: remove the svg using d3.select('#element').remove() and render the graph again

Comment: when i add d3.select('#element').remove(); it is not working for me.if possible can u see my code?? what is wrong in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the answer below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
var data = [
  {
    "indzone": "DO3Zone",
    "totalplot": 1506,
    "allotted": 604,
    "vacant": 625,
    "amenities": 27
  },
  {
    "indzone": "MysuruZone",
    "totalplot": 1382,
    "allotted": 752,
    "vacant": 325,
    "amenities": 27
  },
  {
    "indzone": "BallariZone",
    "totalplot": 920,
    "allotted": 701,
    "vacant": 65,
    "amenities": 34
  },
  {
    "indzone": "BelagaviZone",
    "totalplot": 2650,
    "allotted": 2188,
    "vacant": 262,
    "amenities": 45
  }
];

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


  var ageNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return (key !== "indzone" || key !== 'totalplot') ; });

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.ages = ageNames.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });
  });

  x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.indzone; }));
  x1.domain(ageNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.ages, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Population");

  var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "state")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.indzone) + ",0)"; });

  state.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(ageNames.slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });



</script>
```